# Script Sharp unit testing supported?

Tags: script#

For the 2008 version, you mentioned Unit Testing Support (Coming soon), is it now possible to do unit testing? What are my options to circumvent related issues?

Thanks
CL

Answer (score 2):

In terms of an end-to-end solution, no, not yet.

Here's what has been planned/prototyped, and what you can do in the meantime.

1. Support for writing test classes with test methods... specifically [TestClass], [TestMethod] attributes (as well as setup/cleanup etc. methods)
   This would produce Foo.test.js in addition to Foo.js and Foo.debug.js... which contains all the test code compiled to script as well.
2. A test harness that would run all test classes/methods.
   This is the part that needs most work on before the feature is released. I'd like to build something like the Silverlight unit testing framework.

For #1, you could use conditional code (#ifdef TEST), and create a test build flavor where you define the TEST variable. This will let you compile test code into script without it going into your release script.

For #2, you'd load up your scripts in a page that makes calls to the specific tests. You could write as sophisticated of a harness as you need - either manually hardcoded to call specific tests, or more generic that looks at tests by inspecting the scripts that were loaded into the page.